# Cannot start WebSite because port 80 is being used by W3SVC.exe

Tags: port, services, iis-7

I have deverloped a website at work and we typically use port 80/443 for our websites (in development). This has worked well until today when starting the website gives me the error (IIS 7)

> This Web site cannot be started. Another Web site may be using the same port.

Now I used netstat to find the process id (PID) holding that port 80:

```
netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80
TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

Which gives me in the TaskManager

```
System    4   SYSTEM  00   56 K   NT Kernal & System
```

After a bit of [goggling](http://techreviews.in/port-80-unavailable-step-by-step-guide-to-release-port-80-and-make-it-available-for-apache-server/) I see that it could be the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" which when stopped does clear the port 80 ownership.

However in doing so I am unable to start my website:

> The World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC) is stopped.  Web sites cannot be started unless the World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC) is running.

So now I have a chicken-egg issue where the W3SVC service needs to run to start the web-site yet it being on prevents the web-sites from starting. I don't want to change all application to use another port as that would require a bit of work and it was working yesterday.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem to you. Were you ever able to figure out the solution to this problem?

Comment: +1 here.. 
All sites are on port 8080.. all sites stopped.. port 80 is still busy !!

Answer (score -1):

Try looking in IIS manager, right-clicking on the default web site and selecting `Edit Bindings`.  Check that you don't have any extra/blank bindings to port 80.  You may need to remove an empty binding.